# How to open a modal inside a rendered list in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am rendering a list, and have a button that says "Expand". I want that when this button is clicked, it opens a modal with content that is fetched.

I'm trying to render the `name` inside the data, the same way I'm (correctly) rendering the `date` property. This can be seen in the following code:

```html
<li v-for="data in tableData" v-bind:key="data">
  <button v-on:click="openModal()">{{data.date}}</button>
  <sweet-modal ref="modal">{{data.name}}</sweet-modal>
</li>
```

And the function that opens the modal looks like this:

```
openModal(){
   // let vc = this; I have also tried calling vc.$refs.modal.open()
   this.$refs.modal.open()
}
```

I'm getting a `this.$refs.modal.open is not a function` and I suspect that it is because `this` must be used in some clever way in the function that opens the modal.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your "this" reference. Did you console log what `this.$refs.modal` gets you?

Comment: @CathyHa Ha it throws: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'modal' of undefined"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the main issue is that you're **rendering** a modal component **for each** list item, which might not be what you want.

What you could do instead is to declare the modal outside of any other element and when you click a list item, you'd store that item in a variable and then you open the modal which will show the contents of that variable.

```html
<template>
 <sweet-modal ref='modal'>
    {{crtSelectedItem.name}}
 </sweet-modal>

 <li v-for="data in tableData" v-bind:key="data">
    <button v-on:click='openModal(data)'>{{data.date}}</button>
</li>

<!-- ... -->
</template>
```

```
export default {
 data: () => ({ crtSelectedItem: null }),

 methods: {
  openModal (item) {
    this.crtSelectedItem = { ...item };
    this.$refs.modal.open();
  }
 }
}
```